# Clarifications on Router with ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm a bit puzzled on how things are supposed to work there. I'm trying to follow different tutorials with multiple outlets but most of the time the result is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'apath'

I have a lot of questions:

1) How **forChild declarations** are supposed to behave, especially when declaring the same component with different routes?
-> For instance, every time your generate a new page with the CLI, a new page.module.ts is created, and also the app.routing.module.ts is updated with the route of your new component in a LzyLoaded fashion.
But in the new module there is also a route like :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SortPopoverPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [SortPopoverPage]
})
export class SortPopoverPageModule {}
```

As I get it, this route is going to be concatenated to the other routes declared inapp.routing.module, and it will never be reached since the empty path is already redirected to home.
Why is this route created by the CLI?

2) **Syntax of auxiliary routes**: I saw in the official guide https://angular.io/guide/router syntax like **/path(outlet:path)** but I also saw in other tutorials **/path/(outlet:path)** 
https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-tabs-layout-with-angular-routing-and-ionic-4/

Which one is the good one?

3) Why are we even writing down the destination outlet in route declaration, when you have to specify it in the URL? What happens if you try to load in a different outlet a path declared with a different outlet?

```
{
    path: 'filter',
    outlet: 'popover',
    component: FilterPopoverPage
  }
```

And

```
 <ion-item href="/home(popover:test/filter)">test</ion-item>
```

4)To be more specific: I'm trying to load a component in a dedicated outlet when clicking on a link:

home.html:

```
<ion-content>
...
<ion-item href="/home(popover:filter)">test</ion-item>
...
<ion-router-outlet name="popover"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-content>
```

app.routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomePage},
  {path: 'filter', outlet: 'popover', component: FilterPopoverPage},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

When I clic on the test button, nothing happens, I think the page is reloaded but no error is in the console.
If I use the path /home/(popover:filter) I get the error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'home'

When "home" path is clearly defined... isn't it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? We have the same problem! Thx!

Comment: @MichaelBurger I'm sorry I didn't! I just didn't use the router mechanism to achieve what I wanted, I used ngIf and transition animations... I'd really like todig into that but that's a shame no one could clarify all these questions. Maybe if you upvote the question it could have more chance to be answered.